# Make gzprintf ignore locale LC_NUMERIC

Tags: c, locale, zlib

How can I make `gzprintf` (or printf in general) to use "." as decimal separator, effectively ignoring LC_NUMERIC or using "LC_NUMERIC = C".

Background: My program which uses `gettext` , does `setlocale (LC_ALL, ....)` to change it's locale. But at one point I need to write to a measurement file which should have a fixed "." as decimal separator. Of course I can do something like

```
const char *old = setlocale (LC_NUMERIC, NULL);
... make copy
setlocale (LC_NUMERIC, "C");
... use gzprintf
setlocale (LC_NUMERIC, old_copy);
```

but I fear runtime problems because I have to write samples with 2kHz to the file but haven't benchmarked it yet.

Comment: Yes a  challenging problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only is wrapping each call with `setlocale` like that potentially slow. It's completely thread-unsafe and thus unsafe to use in general/library code.

Assuming you're on a POSIX or POSIX-like system, what you want is `newlocale`/`uselocale`. Perform the following (which may be slow) once and save the result:

```
locale_t safe_locale = newlocale(LC_NUMERIC_MASK, "C", duplocale(LC_GLOBAL_LOCALE));
```

Then, whenever you want to use it:

```
locale_t old = uselocale(safe_locale);
/* Do stuff with it. */
uselocale(old);
```

You need not switch back and forth around each operation, only before returning to a caller that might expect its locale to be undisturbed, but it should not be slow to switch back and forth like this anyway.

Alternatively, just don't honor `LC_NUMERIC` in your application at all. After calling `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` to setup the locale according to the user's settings, call `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C")` and leave it that way. This is not valid/acceptable in library code, but if you're writing library code, you can punt and let the caller take responsibility for doing whichever approach it finds appropriate (never honoring `LC_NUMERIC` at all, or using `newlocale`/`uselocale` to switch). You can either just write this requirement in the documentation of its contract, and treat failure to honor the contract as undefined, or you can actively test for non-`'.'` radix point by asserting that `localeconv()->decimal_point` points to a string `"."` (and returning an error or aborting if that fails to hold).